# Electric field at location of a charge due to the charge itself?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Suppose a charge $Q$ is put in the space at point $(x',y',z')$. What is the electric field value at point $(x',y',z')$?

Comment: Essentially, are you asking what is the electric field due to a point charge at the location of the point charge?

Comment: Yes, you got it right...

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193290/does-a-point-charge-exert-force-on-itself

Answer (score 2):

This is the electric field of a point charge:

[image: Efield point charge]  [image]

> [The electric field](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html) is radially outward from the point charge in all directions. The circles represent spherical equipotential surfaces.

Notice the r in the denominator. For r=0, which is your question, the field becomes infinite. In **classical** electrodynamics a particle can never have zero dimensions because the charge has to be carried by some medium, and the point source is an approximation. What the field will be at r=0 will depend on the material the "point" source is made of.  Some examples are [here](http://web.mit.edu/8.02-esg/Spring03/www/8.02ch24we.pdf).

In **quantum** electrodynamics the elementary particles are point sources  but the classical field concept does not have a meaning in QED  . One deals with creation and annihilation [operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28physics%29) and has photons mediating interactions thus the infinities of the classical equations are avoided.